# Full width menu with negative margin gives infinite horizontal scroll on safari and ios

Tags: ios, css, safari, margin

I have a site where I have a full width menu, which has negative margins. It works perfect, except on Safari/iOS.

On Safari/iOS I can scroll horizontaly forever....WHY?

```
 background-color: #0a6e96;
 margin: -1px -9999rem;
 padding: 1.2rem 9999rem;
 margin-top: 48px;
```

Update - Solution

https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

This link has multiple solutions.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using negative margins?

Comment: To fill the screen width...

Comment: This article solved my problem: https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/  - I switched from negative margin to box shadow. Thank you for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid triggering horizontal scrolling, you need to set `overflow-x:hidden` on both the `html` and `body` elements.